# How to print a range based on two lists, from the user input entered?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, range

So basically, I want to write a python program where based on two lists, such as this:

```
minsalary = [22000,41000,10000,51500,13000]

maxsalary = [35000,95000,34000,65000,31000]
```

The user enters an input and based on the input, the program prints out the range based on input AND position. Each index corresponds to a job and range. So index(position) 0 in minsalary and index 0 in maxsalary both are a range that corresponds to job 0. So from 22000 to 35000 at index 0 is a job in itself.

It is based on maximum salary, each range corresponds to an index(or job position)
So if user enters 30000, program would print the best range would be 22000 to 35000 based on position 0 (index).

Comment: What is the rule here? Choose two elements from `minsalary` and `maxsalary` that have minimum differences with the user input?

Comment: And I believe the position is only based on `maxsalary`?

Comment: Yeah it's essentially based on the best range that minimizes differences. So if user is interested in like in a salary of let's say 30000, the best would probably be 22000 to 35000.

Comment: Why 35000 and not 31000?

Comment: Oh because it has a smaller range, their starting salary could anywhere from 22000 to 35000. Each position corresponds to different jobs. So this is job number 0, based on the index.

Comment: All of these extra information should be included in the post. Please edit to include so people don't have to look through the comments (which SO doesn't like either). In the meantime, give the answer a try.

Comment: Correction: It's based on maximum salary offered, sorry for confusion! 35000 seems better to 31000.

Comment: What have you attempted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work without mixing up min/max values of different indexes (e.g. 33000):

```
minsalary = [22000,41000,10000,51500,13000]
maxsalary = [35000,95000,34000,65000,31000]
salary    = 14000
index     = min((b-a,i) for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(minsalary,maxsalary)) if salary in range(a,b+1))[1]
print(f'Best range is {minsalary[index]} to {maxsalary[index]}, use position {index}')
```

Here is a broken down version to better isolate each step:

```
ranges          = zip(minsalary,maxsalary)  # [ (min,max), (min,max), ... ]
indexedRanges   = enumerate(ranges)         # [ (0,(min,max)), (1,(min,max)) ... ]
eligibleIndexes = [ (b-a,i) for i,(a,b) in indexedRanges if salary>=a and salary <= b ] # [ (size,2), (size,4) ]
smallest        = min(eligibleIndexes) # (size,4)
index           = smallest[1]
print(f'Best range is {minsalary[index]} to {maxsalary[index]}, use position {index}')
```

- The `ranges` variable converts the two arrays into an array of tuples with (minimum,maximu) salaries in the ranges.
- The `indexedRanges` variable adds the index (position) to the ranges tuples
- The `eligibleIndexes` filters `indexedRanges` to only keep the items where the salary is inside the range and returns the range size and the corresponding index
- The `smallest` variable receives the minimum entry of `eligibleIndexes` which is the one with the smallest range size.  The result is a tuple with the size and index.
- The `index` of the best eligible range is the second part of the `smallest` tuple.

Comment: Yes this seems to work! I am still a beginner so I'm trying to grasp certain concepts. I didn't know how to solve this problem mainly due to the fact that there is two lists to deal with.

Comment: Do you happen to have a different version of your program that is more beginner friendly? I want to trace through it and better learn from it, I would appreciate it!

Comment: One last thing,if the user enters a number outside the range, it generates an error, how could I modify the program to avoid that?

Comment: Depends on how you want to handle it.  If it's not a normal condition, you could enclose the line(s) inside a try: except: statement.  If it is a normal condition, you could add a huge range at the end of the array as a fallback for the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Using built-in `min` with `key`:

```
minsalary = [22000,41000,10000,51500,13000]

maxsalary = [35000,95000,34000,65000,31000] 

def ranger(user_input):
    lower = min(minsalary, key = lambda x: abs(x-user_input))
    upper = min(maxsalary, key = lambda x: abs(x-user_input))
    print('Best range is %s to %s, use position %s' % (lower, upper, maxsalary.index(upper)))
```

Output:

```
ranger(13000)
# Best range is 13000 to 31000, use position 4
```